# Schedule a query in Bigquery when a table come in Firebase Analytics Partition table

Tags: google-bigquery, scheduler, firebase-analytics

I am using the data exported from Firebase Analytics to Google Bigquery.
Those table are partition by date in this format ProjectID.Dataset.table_YYYYMMDD
example
`` SELECT * FROM `PROJECTIID.analyticsxxxx.events_YYYYMMDD` LIMIT 1000 `` 
Unfortunately those table comes everyday on different time ( sometimes 10am , sometimes 5 am , sometimes 2 pm)
I wonder if there is a way to use the "Scheduled queries" functionality of Bigquery with a "if" condition.

The If condition on my case will be to have a sensor to check if the partition table of yesterday is in than the scheduled query can run , if not wait until the table comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use metatable `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` to check for table existence and [BigQuery scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#if) inside scheduled query like:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FROM <dataset>.__TABLES_SUMMARY__ WHERE table_id='mytablename') 
THEN
  ...
END IF;
```